Frequent semi-hard system freezes 22.04 LTS
I did search online and here on the forum for similar posts but found none that fits the issue.
A Framework laptop bought in 2022 with the following specs:

16GB RAM
11th Gen i5-1135G7 2.4GHzx8
Mesa Intel Xe Graphics
500GB SSD
running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
GNOME 42.9
Wayland

There is no driver or software updates available at the moment, as it checks for updates daily.
Everything, except the keyboard and audio, freezes regularly since maybe a week ago. The freeze may occur minutes or hours after boot, regardless of what software I am using. Overheating shouldn't be an issue, as I only use the laptop on a stand with lots of clear room below and do not run anything crazier than Firefox and Discord.
Now, the freeze may disappear after 5-45 minutes, but usually once one has occurred, more follow in quick succession. I can close the laptop to force a login, which fixes the freeze temporarily. Serious work is impossible that way, though.
My attempts

run top command -> memory peaks at 3% usage, but CPU sometimes reaches up to 30%
check for updates -> none available
restart and control temperature when retesting

I'm new to Linux and don't know what logs I could access to give you a better picture, so please bear with me. Everything ran flawlessly for the past six months and I never had to dive into Linux/Ubuntu much at all. What steps should I take to identify the cause and remedy it? Maybe you guys have a hunch what is going on? Thank you.

Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show system logs that cover the event.  Each log message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in [] of the issuer and a colon (:). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read man logger, for a clearer explanation.

Same problem here, similar specs with the following minor differences: Framework 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8; Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2). It's worked fine for over a year after buying used, then abruptly started freezing a couple days ago with the same behavior (can close lid to force it out of the UI freeze, audio keeps playing, doesn't seem to matter what apps I'm using, multiple happen in succession, then it's OK for a day or so).

Have you considered upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04? If so, I'd be curious to hear whether it fixed the issues for you (or anything else you did to get things working again).

Possibly related: Short freezes on Ubuntu 22.04 although these are a good deal shorter than the ones described here.

Update since my last comment: the issue seems to have fixed itself through normal updates, staying on Ubuntu 22.04. I haven't had a freeze in a month.

Edit: I'm Currently on kernel version 6.11 zabbly and the issue came back. It might actually have come back in 6.10 already. I solved it by downgrading to the official 5.15 kernel as suggested by HenrikB. 5.15 was no longer installed so I installed it with:
sudo apt install linux-image-generic
I then configured Grub to remember the last manual selection. Finally, I selected 5.15 at boot. I think that every time there is a kernel update, the order is reset, so I need to manually select 5.15 again.
I'm quite surprised that this bug is lasting so long, I think the X1C is quite popular among Linux users. It would be great if someone could report if the issue exists on Ubuntu 24.04 too.

I had the same issue on my Lenovo Thinkpad X1C Gen 9, very annoying. I think the issue started after an update, probably around mid-August 2024. I don't know what the source of the issue was, but I upgraded the kernel to 6.10 and since then I haven't experienced any freeze.
To update the kernel I used Zabbly's repos -- see instruction in the readme of the repo. The repo should be trusted (the maintainer has worked at Canonical until recently, see here) and the procedure is straightforward, but I did have to disable Secure Boot, which is not great. As soon as I have a moment I'll just upgrade to 24.04 with the official kernel, which I hope is not affected.

